# Как интегрировать RabbitMQ с Wordpress? (php-amqplib)

Tags: php, wordpress, rabbitmq

На сайте нужно реализовать к примеру какие-то real-time odds, с удаленного сервера будут приходить данные, которые мне нужно отобразить на вп-сайте.
На сервисе это реализовано на RabbitMQ, читал доки по RabbitMQ (php-amqplib), по примерах все получается, но не имею представления как отображать данные на веб-странице а не в консоли, как это вообще реализовывается, в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Попробуйте этот плагин https://github.com/devrahul/Wordpress-RabbitMQ

Comment: @KAGGDesign, установил, прописал конфиги, документация к нему есть какая?)

Comment: Не знаю, я вот только ссылку видел ...

Answer (score 1):

Для интеграции WordPress с RabbitMQ есть три варианта:

- [Плагин WP-Minions от 10up](https://github.com/10up/WP-Minions)
- [Плагин Wordpress-RabbitMQ от devrahul](https://github.com/devrahul/Wordpress-RabbitMQ)
- [Мост через интеграции n8n](https://n8n.io/integrations/rabbitmq/and/wordpress/)

Наиболее простой и оптимальный вариант - использовать плагин **WP-Minions**. Всё зависит от ваших задач.